# Getting "An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: " error when trying to decode the jwt token

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt

this is my Security configuration file for resource server

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecureSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("api/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
}
```

and those are dependencies for spring boot application (resource server app.)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

here is the jwk-set-url in the config yml file, to which my application is connecting at start up

```
    spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8083/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
```

And via postman now when I'm getting the token from auth server via postman and trying to request to my server, I'm getting this kind of error

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 null", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
```

who has faced such kind of issue?

Comment: Hello, my friend from on*olve)

Answer (score -2):

Change the "Hostname Verification" to "none" in SSL properties tab.

Comment: Dear ujjwal dixit, would you please tell a little more details about what you said?
you mean in postman?